# Check letter in word [hangman]

Tags: javascript

I'm new in programming.I have to write hangman game i javascript and have a big problem :D This is my function.The problem is : when user enter right letter it is appears in Wrong Guess too and I don't know why.

```
function IsLetterInWord(letter)
{
    for(i = 0; i< Word.length; i++)
        {
        if(letter == Word[i])
        {
            secretword[i] == letter;
            RightGuess += letter;
            var el = document.getElementById("right");
            el.innerHTML = "Your right guesses are:" + RightGuess;
            win();
        }

        }
if (letter != Word[i]){
            WrongGuess += letter;
            var e = document.getElementById("wrong");
            e.innerHTML = "Your wrong guesses are:" + WrongGuess;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use of the `indexOf()` method.The method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.
 [Link to docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
"string".indexOf("r") > -1;
```

You also need to use single equals on line #7:

```
secretword[i] = letter; // instead of ==
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a problem with your logic: you're treating a letter as wrong if it doesn't match *every* letter in the target, whereas it should only count as wrong if it doesn't match *any* letter. Also, a wrong letter should only count once, whereas a right letter should count for each match.

Just as a matter of developing good habits (though it makes no real difference in something as small as this), try not to repeat DOM operations unnecessarily since they're fairly slow. Things like

```
var el = document.getElementById("right");
```

should be done *before* a loop rather than inside it (the identity of the element plainly isn't going to change) and things like

```
el.innerHTML = "Your right guesses are:" + RightGuess;
```

should only be done *after* the loop finishes (the browser has to redraw part of the screen each time it's called).